# Unsure on the pronouns/verbs/tense to use here

Tags: word-choice, tenses, questions

This question came up when answering tickets today at work. A client says they've been having one singular problem across multiple entries. How should I phrase my response?

"Which entries was this happening on?"
or
"What entries was this happening on?"

Neither of these sound right. Is the issue tense? i.e.:

"Which entries has this been happening on?"

I'm pretty sure 'which' should be correct because I'm asking for specific entries from a list.

What's the correct option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awkwardness comes from splitting *which/what* and *on*.

Try: **On which entries did this problem occur?**

or, if you like the sound of it better: *For which entries did this problem happen?*

"Which" is better than "What" because you are asking about specific individual entries.

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed the preposition being at the end of the sentence there.

Comment: Just passing by when I noticed that your answer, though selected, had no up-votes, so ... +1 @Joel Brown

Comment: Cant upvote without 15 rep :(

Answer (score 0):

To my ear,

> "Which entries did this happen with?" [for a discrete set of events]

or

> "Which entries has this been happening with?" [for events occurring over an extended period]

are the most natural-sounding wordings.